# Is it possible to cream clarified butter with sugar? Will it have the same benefits as shortening and oil?

Tags: baking, cake, cookies, leavening

Is it really possible to cream clarified butter? And considering that clarified butter is 100% fat, am I correct in assuming you'd get the taste of butter and also the leavening benefits of shortening if it was creamed with sugar? And when melted, would it work just like oil?  Basically the best of butter, shortening and oil into one?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it really possible to cream clarified butter [with sugar]?

Sure, why not?

> And considering that clarified butter is 100% fat, am I correct in assuming you'd get the taste of butter and also the leavening benefits of shortening if it was creamed with sugar?

You would get the taste of clarified butter (and sugar, of course), but that's somewhat different from the taste of regular butter. The "leavening benefits" of creamed butter are pretty minimal, but they'd still be there.

> And when melted, would it work just like oil?

Well, like melted clarified butter with sugar on the bottom, sure. The creaming wouldn't really have an effect here.

Comment: Wouldn't the leavening benefits increase with clarified butter though?  It's pure fat,  like shortening (which is known to provide more of a leavening boost than creamed butter).

Comment: I don't see why it would. If anything, I would expect the residual lecithin in the butter to help entrain air; but clarified butter won't have any lecithin.